# Oracle forms where clause with a variable from bloc item

Tags: sql, forms, oracle

I'm trying to populate a block using a `FROM` clause in oracle forms like this:

```
Select  h.no_ordre, 
        h.marge,
        h.date_modification, 
        h.utilisateur_modification 
From    hist_marge_0alb h, 
        simul           s, 
        simtauxvar_0alb sv, 
        affaire         a 
Where   s.id_affaire = a.id_affaire 
And     s.id_simul_element(+) = h.id_simul_element 
And     sv.id_simul_element = s.id_simul_element 
And     s.id_affaire = :SIMUL.id_affaire
```

But i got a FRM 40505 Error. I think the problem is in `:SIMUL.id_affaire` but I don't find a way to do it.

Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: Have you included parentheses `()` around the query?

Comment: Oh, and you can't refer to item values in the query. https://community.oracle.com/thread/576588